# installation problem ubuntu 18.04 on msi GL63 8RE laptop

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 in my msi GL63 8RE laptop. In grub i used modprobe.blacklist=1 acpi=off. But after the installation when restart the system in didn't reboot.

Comment: See this link https://gist.github.com/mari-linhares/cef4cb3440408e44963d1447a7db5ae0